# How to return error message/null from a method whose return type is int?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# method whose signature is as follows:

`public int MyMethod(string myString)`

I am accessing the database, searching for a tuple in a table, and then getting the `Id` of the tuple. This `Id` will be returned from this method. However, I want to return either `null` or ideally, an error message on the screen if this tuple is not found in the table. How can I do that?

My sample:

```
try
{
    ...
    ...
    if(dataFromDB != null)
    {
        ...
        return dataFromDB.Id;
    }
}
catch(Exception myException)
{
    ...
}
return ...;
```

Comment: 1. Throw an exception on failure. 2. Write a method that returns true for success and false for failure, and passes back the `id` or the error message in a pair of `out` parameters. Or have it return `string`, pass back the `id` in an `out` parameter, and return null for success, or an error message on failure.

Comment: Another option is returning a custom object type that indicates what happened. Ex: interface IMyMethodResult, and two implementing classes such as  SuccessMyMethodResult, FailureMyMethodResult. The calling code can then check what type got returned to figure out whether to display a success or error message, and each type would contain the properties that are applicable to that situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can return multiple values from a method using the concept of [Tuple class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=netframework-4.8) and change your method in this way:

```
public (int id, string message) GetDataFromDB()
{
    if(dataFromDB == null)
        return ( 0, "Data not found");
    else
        return (dataFromDB.Id, "");
}
```

and call it in this way

```
var result = GetDataFromDB();
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.message))
    Console.WriteLine("Success, found ID=" + result.id);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failure: " + result.message);
```

This can be used [starting with C# 7.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

Comment: The Tuple concept was introduced with .NET Framework 4.0. C# 7 added a new syntax to handle them, before it the syntax was: public Tuple<int, string> GetValues()
{
     return Tuple.Create(1,"");
}

Comment: Actually, C# 7 did not add a new syntax to handle **them**, it introduced a completely new set of tuple types with support from the new syntax. `Tuple<...>` was left in the dust and is not supported by this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I dislike returning values OR error messages from the same method. I believe that methods should return values or throw exceptions, and it's up to the UI to interpret the result and display the appropriate message in the appropriate way.

You can always make the method return a [Nullable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/). and return null when a value is not found. Like so:

```
        public int? MyMethod(string myString)
        {
            try
            {

            if (dataFromDB != null)
            {
                return dataFromDB.Id;
            }
            catch (Exception myException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```